# Is it possible to use XDebug on code running in a Beanstalkd queue?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, beanstalkd

I have XDebug configured to work with PhpStorm. It works on synchronous code, but does not on code that is running in a queue.

Is it possible to make this happen? How do I do it?

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? Breakpoints are not being hit or something else? Any example of a queue code that doesn't work?

Comment: Exactly. Breakpoints don't get hit. The code running in the queue is identical to my synchronous code.

Comment: Please enable *Run | Break at first line in PHP scripts* and check if it will break in the affected files.